# Searching by tag in Hadoop 2.6.5 using YarnClient

Tags: hadoop, tags, hadoop-yarn

I might be missing something here, but I think there is no way to search by applicationTags in Hadoop 2.6.5.

The 2.6.5 docs here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html have *no* mention of application tags.

However the most recent versions of Hadoop *do*:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html

```
abstract List<ApplicationReport>    getApplications(Set<String> applicationTypes, EnumSet<YarnApplicationState> applicationStates, Set<String> applicationTags)
```

I am pretty sure there is no way to do this without using the REST API instead of YarnClient; I'm avoiding the REST API for a few reasons (I can't find a way to test with it using mini clusters due to a bug I think, and also the YarnClient is convenient if it's already there instead of me making a rest client myself)

Comment: Do tags exist in that version of Hadoop? How about the 2.7 or 2.8 clients? Are you not able to update just that client library via Maven?

Comment: I could try updating the client, but there is no reason to assume it will work beyond just luck at that point.  Tags do exist; you can use them as a filter parameter in the ResourceManager REST API . Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth poking around github or jira tickets to see when those client methods were added

Comment: That's a good idea.  I know it first showed up on 2.9.0 per the docs.

Comment: We are using 2.9.2 YarnClient in same project with 2.6.5 dependencies.  Works so far; will update when it surely breaks for some reason :)